# Firestore rules compare reference to constructed path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my `company` documents, I have a reference field named `owner`, which points to a `user` document. In the rule, I am trying to check if the authenticated uid is the owner of the company:

```
match /companies/{companyId} {
  allow read: if isOwner(resource.data.owner, request.auth.uid);
}



function isOwner(owner, userId) {
   return path('/users/' + userId) == owner;
}
```

I tried many things but can't figure out how to make this work.

(I know using a string instead of a reference works, but I would rather use a reference)

Comment: Update: on "rules_version 2" ; its gonna work with this : "allow read: if resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you construct the path, include this prefix: `/databases/(default)/documents/`. It's part of the full path to a document.

```
match /companies/{companyId} {
  allow read: if isOwner(resource.data.owner, request.auth.uid);
}

function isOwner(owner, userId) {
   return path('/databases/(default)/documents/users/' + userId) == owner;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should enable you to compare on the reference field.

```
match /companies/{companyId} {

allow read: if /databases/$(database)/documents/user/$(request.auth.uid) == resource.data.owner

}
```

**Note: resource.data.owner NOT request.resource.data.owner**

Answer (score 0):

Why not making an ownerId field in the compagny document and check if the authenticated user uid is equal to the value?

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /companies/{compagnyId} {
            allow read: if isOwner()
        }
    }
}

function currentData() {
    return resource.data
}

function isOwner() {
    return currentData().ownerId == request.auth.uid
}
```